# Does the limit $\lim _{x\to 0} \frac 1x \int_0^x \left|\cos \frac 1t \right| dt$ exists?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, riemann-integration

Does the limit $\lim _{x\to 0} \frac 1x \int_0^x \left|\cos \frac 1t \right| dt$ exists ? If it does then what is the value ?

I don't think even L'Hospital's rule can be applied . Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: May i know why L'Hospital's can't be applied?

Comment: Can you find $\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^xf(t)\,dt$ ?

Comment: L' Hospital will not work.  What is $\lim_{x \to 0}  |\cos(1/x)|$?

Answer (score 8):

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac1x\int_0^x\left|\,\cos\left(\frac1t\right)\,\right|\mathrm{d}t
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}x\int_x^\infty\frac{|\cos(t)|}{t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}(x+n\pi)\sum_{k=n}^\infty\int_x^{x+\pi}\frac{|\cos(t)|}{(t+k\pi)^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Using the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula,
$$
\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac{x+n\pi}{(t+k\pi)^2}
=\frac{x+n\pi}{\pi(t+n\pi)}+\frac{x+n\pi}{2(t+n\pi)^2}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\tag{2}
$$
Thus, for $x\le t\le x+\pi$,we have
$$
\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac{x+n\pi}{(t+k\pi)^2}=\frac1\pi+O\!\left(\frac1n\right)\tag{3}
$$
and therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac1x\int_0^x\left|\,\cos\left(\frac1t\right)\,\right|\mathrm{d}t
&=\frac1\pi\int_0^\pi|\cos(t)|\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac2\pi\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Very nice +1.  I realized too late that I can't get the cancelation needed as with $\int_0^x \cos(1/t) \, dt.$

Answer (score 4):

As en alternative for the powerfull Euler-Maclaurin asymptotics in @robjohn answer one can use simple zero order approximations and the Squeeze theorem.

1. The estimate for $x+\pi k\le t\le x+\pi(k+1)$ 
   $$
   \frac{|\cos t|}{(x+\pi(k+1))^2}\le \frac{|\cos t|}{t^2}\le \frac{|\cos t|}{(x+\pi k)^2}
   $$
   and integration gives 
   $$
   \frac{2}{(x+\pi(k+1))^2}\le\int_{x+\pi k}^{x+\pi(k+1)}\frac{|\cos t|}{t^2}\,dt\le\frac{2}{(x+\pi k)^2}.
   $$
2. Further estimation by the integrals
   $$
   \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{x+\pi(k+1)}^{x+\pi(k+2)}\frac{1}{t^2}\,dt\le \frac{2}{(x+\pi(k+1))^2}\le\ldots\le 
   \frac{2}{(x+\pi k)^2}\le \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{x+\pi(k-1)}^{x+\pi k}\frac{1}{t^2}\,dt
   $$
   and summing up for $0\le k<+\infty$ gives
   $$
   \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{x+\pi}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t^2}\,dt\le \int_x^{\infty}\frac{|\cos t|}{t^2}\,dt\le \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{x-\pi}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t^2}\,dt.
   $$
3. Calculate the integral estimates and multiply by $x$
   $$
   \frac{2}{\pi}\frac{x}{x+\pi}\le x\int_x^{\infty}\frac{|\cos t|}{t^2}\,dt\le \frac{2}{\pi}\frac{x}{x-\pi}.
   $$
   Take the limit as $x\to\infty$ and use the [Squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).

Comment: This is a great supplementary answer.