# If $f$ has antiderivative, must $|f|$ also have antiderivative?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose function $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ has an antiderivative. This means there is some differentiable function $F$ so that $f(x) = F'(x)$ in all of $[a,b]$.

Must the absolute value $|f|$ have an antiderivative?

What if we also specify that $f$ is Riemann integrable?  I know that if $f$ is Riemann integrable, then $|f|$ must be also, but not every integrable function has an antiderivative.

Comment: Even if $f$ is continuous it is a little hard to construct the antiderivative of $|f|$ explicitly from $F$: First we need take a countable family of disjoint intervals $(a_n,b_n)$ of $[a,b]$ with dense union (i.e each $a_n$ is also $b_m$ and vice-versa, except possibly at the boundary points $a,b$) such that $f$ is either positive, negative, or zero on each interval. Take an antiderivative of $|f|$ on each $(a_n,b_n)$ ($F$ or $-F$). Then an antiderivative of $|f|$ needs to be constructed by translates of $F$ and $-F$ in a step-by-step manner.

Comment: @SAS: For clarification are you not asking if the existence of $F$ such that $F'(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ implies that there exists $G$ such that $G'(x) = |f(x)|$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.

Comment: @RRL: Yes that is correct.  Was something not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your understanding of the term antiderivative is correct. A function $F:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is an antiderivative of $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$, if it is differentiable and $F'(x) = f(x)$ for **all** $x \in [a,b]$.

It seems then the question is if $f$ has an antiderivative, then is it necessary that the function $x \mapsto |f(x)|$ has an antiderivative.  Specifically, does there exist differentiable $G:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $G'(x) = |f(x)|$ for **all** $x \in [a,b]$?

The answer is **no**  -- it is not necessary.

A counterexample is

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}\cos(x^{-1}), & 0 < x \leqslant   1 \\ 0, & x= 0 \end{cases}$$

Here $f$ has an antiderivative

$$F(x) = \int_0^x \cos (t^{-1}) \, dt$$

Since $f$ is continuous on $(0,1]$ we have, directly by the FTC, that $F'(x) = \cos(x^{-1})$ for $0 < x \leqslant 1$.  We can also verify that $F(0) = 0$ and

$$\tag{*}F'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{F(x) - F(0)}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x \cos (t^{-1}) \, dt = 0 = f(0) $$

The details of deriving the limit (*) are given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3085511/148510).

On the other hand, we have

$$g(x) = |f(x)| = \begin{cases}|\cos(x^{-1})|, & 0 < x \leqslant   1 \\ 0, & x= 0 \end{cases}$$

Suppose there exists an antiderivative $G$ such that $G'(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. Since $g$ is Riemann integrable (continuous except at one endpoint), it follows by the FTC that

$$G(x) - G(0) = \int_0^x g(t) \, dt$$

By continuity of $g$, clearly have  $G'(x) = |\cos(x^{-1}|$ for $0 < x \leqslant 1$.

However,

$$\tag{**}G'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{G(x) - G(0)}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x |\cos (t^{-1})| \, dt = \frac{2}{\pi} \neq 0 =  g(0) $$

The details of deriving the limit (**) are given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2063115/148510) in robjohn's answer.

This proves that no such antiderivative $G$ exists.

**Aside**

The issue of integrability of $f$ is peripheral as there are Riemann integrable functions without antiderivatives.  Furthermore, if we have

$$F(x) = \int_{[a,x]} f,$$

as a Lebesgue integral and $F'(x) = f(x)$ almost everywhere but not for every $x \in [a,b]$, then $F$ does not qualify as an antiderivative.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense. How did you arrive at such counterexample?

Answer (score 2):

Note the following quote from the [wikipedia article on the Henstock–Kurzweil integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henstock%E2%80%93Kurzweil_integral) (under Properties)

> In general, every Henstock–Kurzweil integrable function is measurable,
>   and **f is Lebesgue integrable if and only if both f and |f| are
>   Henstock–Kurzweil integrable.** This means that the Henstock–Kurzweil
>   integral can be thought of as a "non-absolutely convergent version of
>   Lebesgue integral". It also implies that the Henstock–Kurzweil
>   integral satisfies appropriate versions of the monotone convergence
>   theorem (without requiring the functions to be nonnegative) and
>   dominated convergence theorem (where the condition of dominance is
>   loosened to g(x) ≤ fn(x) ≤ h(x) for some integrable g, h).
>
> **If F is differentiable everywhere (or with countable many exceptions),
>   the derivative F′ is Henstock–Kurzweil integrable, and its indefinite
>   Henstock–Kurzweil integral is F.**

From the highlighted sentences (and the Henstock–Kurzweil differentiation theorem), it follows that if $f$ has an anti-derivative, then $|f|$ will also have an anti-derivative if and only if $f$ is Lesbegue integrable.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution.  I don't think it is correct though, if it only provides diff. everywhere with countable exceptions.

Comment: Perhaps it falls short in providing only an almost-everywhere anti-derivative for $|f|$, but it does show that there are $f$ with anti-derivatives where $|f|$ does not have have one. Any non-Lebesgue Integrable function cannot have anti-derivatives for both $f$ and $|f|$, That is all you got out of the other answer as well. RRL gave you a specific example, which is always nice. But I gave you a necessary condition, which is also sufficient if one relaxes the concept of anti-derivative only slightly.