# the composition of two functions that have primitives has primitives

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> It is common sense that the composition of two **continuous**
> functions is **continuous**.
>
> It is also widely known that the composition of two **derivable**
> functions is **derivable**.

Is it true that the composition of two functions that have **primitives** has **primitives**?

If it is **true** that I would be grateful to have a *demonstration*, otherwise, if it is **false** then I need a **counterexample**.

***Note***: the two functions are defined over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Think of (or look up) a function that does not have a primitive. Can it be written as the composition of functions that do have primitives?

Comment: $f(x)=e^{x^2}$ is the composition of functions $g(x)=e^x$ and $h(x)=x^2$ that have primitives. however $f(x)$ has no primitive (in the sense of Liouville) There are [deep arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(differential_algebra)) of algebra type that explain this.

Answer (score 4):

Take $g(x) = x^2$, which clearly has a primitive.  If the assertion were true then for any function $f$ with a primitive it would follow that $g\circ f = f^2$ would have a primitive.

A counterexample is given by

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}\sin(x^{-1}), & 0 < x \leqslant   1 \\ 0, & x= 0 \end{cases}$$

which has a primitive $F(x) = \int_0^x \sin (t^{-1}) \, dt$ since $F'(x) = \sin (x^{-1})$ for all $0 < x \leqslant 1$ by the FTC and it can be shown that

$$F'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{1}{x} \int_0^x \sin (t^{-1}) \, dt = 0$$

However,

$$f^2(x) =\begin{cases}\sin^2(x^{-1}) , & 0 < x \leqslant   1 \\ 0, & x= 0 \end{cases}$$

and it can be shown that $f^2$ does not have a primitive using a similar argument as given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3214232/148510).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose f is a bounded derivative,  and g is strictly convex. Then gof will be a derivative if and only if  f is approximately continuous.[1].

Thus , for f(x)= sin(1/x)+2, (f(0)=2), neither f^2 nor 1/f will be a derivative.

[1]Differentiation of Real functions,CRM Monograph Series, vol. 5
Ch.9 , Thm.4.3